# Sessions being overridden

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have developed a Laravel 4 application a few years ago which hasn't broken since. All of a sudden users were seeing others users information. Basically what happens is I use Auth::attempt to check the user and, if valid, I use Auth::user() to get the user. What is happening is there is only one session being written to the storage/sessions folder and whenever a new user logs in, this session is overridden with the new values. Hence, it will show the last persons data.  I have used EXACTLY the same solution on another server and it makes a new session whenever someone tries to login.

My question is why is it only creating one session?  How can I fix this please?

It is on a shared hosting platform and I am assuming that with a PHP update or something, something has broken. As mentioned it worked for years and now has stopped which means that it probably is a configuration. Please can you help me?

Source Code:

class SessionsController extends BaseController {

```
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function index()
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function create()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
    return View::make('login');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store()
{
    if (Auth::attempt(array('email'=>Input::get('email'),'password'=>Input::get('password'),'usertype_id'=>'2'))){
        return Redirect::to('/dashboard');
    }

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->with('flash_error', 'Login credentials are incorrect.');
}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function update($id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return Response
 */
public function destroy()
{
    Auth::logout();
    return Redirect::to('/login');
}
```

}

Then I use it as follows in other Controllers:

$student = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->student;

Comment: "written to the storage/sessions folder", how do you know that? You usually don't have access to the sessions directory unless you owns the server and can look into it. How do you use the sessions in php? Please update the question to include the relevant source code.

Comment: In Laravel you can define the session mechanism ie. database, cookie, file etc. If you choose file you can see the files in the storage/sessions folder as you do have access to it. I will update question with source code.